# What is "division sum"?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

What is the meaning of "division sum". I have seen the being used a lot but haven't found an explanation defining the term. Understanding from its usage, it seems to be another term for 'division'. But why call it "division sum"?

Comment: Can you provide a link or reference to where you saw that usage?

Comment: Maybe a way to [compute division](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/in-a-division-sum-we-have-dividend-199-quotient-16-and-remainder/)?

Comment: The *divisor sum* $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ is the sum of all positive divisors of $n$.

Comment: Judging from [this](https://www.math-only-math.com/dividend-divisor-quotient-and-remainder.html#:~:text=Therefore%2C%20to%20check%20a%20division,number%20the%20quotient%20is%20zero.) the phrase refers to the expression $d=aq+r$ as an equivalent for "$\frac da=q$ with a remainder of $r$".  I wouldn't call this standard terminology (I never heard the phrase before just now).

Comment: I believe that in British usage, "sum" can refer to any kind of math problem, e.g. "a sum in Euclid."  So, it may just mean a division problem.  (I'm not British; this is just based on what I've read.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK at least "sums" was used in elementary schools and classes - certainly when I was growing up - to describe lists of problems of the kind: $$a \circ b =?$$

Where $\circ$ stands for one of the operators $+, -, \times, \div$

Probably the use of "sum" comes because they were introduced with $+$ as the simplest operator, becoming more complex as the others were learned.

Such phrases as "your homework is sums", or "now see how quickly you can do all your sums" were routine. And a division sum was simply one of the sums which involved the division operator.

It's all language (and from elementary school exercises) rather than anything sophisticated about definitions.